# CKEditor - formatting editor display changes apostrophe to lsquo

Tags: javascript, mysql, ckeditor

In the frontend display of CKEditor when entering certain characters such as apostrophes (') and double-quotes (") CKEditor automatically converts them as you type to the corresponding left tick (‘, lsquo) and left double quote (“, ldquo). The editor also attempts to convert a second apostrophe or doub-quote to the corresponding right or closed version. I made the following changes to the ckeditor/config.js file with no help:

```
config.htmlEncodeOutput = false;
config.entities = false;
config.entities_latin = false; 
config.htmlEncodeOutput = false;
config.entities_additional = false;
```

This impacts how some data and some characters gets stored in the database, but does not prevent the auto-conversion.

Test that I enter as:

```
Mr O'Toole is "rad."
```

Autoconverts to:

```
Mr O’Toole is “rad.”
```

In the MySQL field it is stored as:

```
Mr O’Toole is “rad.”
```

If I toggle the editor to HTML/CODE view you will also see the conversions. The question of course is how do you configure the editor to not do this type of presumptuous character conversion?

Comment: What is your environment? Is it the "bare" CKEditor, or the ASP.NET integration? What versions do you use?

Comment: Apache, PHP, pretty out of the box. Firefox and Chrome - same.

Comment: Version? how about: ckkeditor_4.4.1_83937d46532f.zip

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the online docs, then someone suggested it could be a plugin but which one. The plugins folder list revealed nothing obvious so curious I looked at the build.config.js file and saw 'autocorrect'. Just guessing I added that to the list of plugins to ignore in the ~/ckeditor/config.js file:

```
config.removePlugins = 'elementspath,autosave,autocorrect';
```

Surprisingly, it worked.